# Making activity singleTask destroys stack after returning?

Tags: android

I'm wondering why making activity singleTask destroys the stack after returning to it. For example, with standard type if we adhere to rules, another instance of first activity should start again, but it doesn't. What's so special in singleTask?
P.S. I saw this discussion:
[Android: bug in launchMode="singleTask"? -> activity stack not preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer at [Android singleTask or singleInstance launch mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219726/android-singletask-or-singleinstance-launch-mode) - which does a good job if explaining the documentation and refers on to an excellent blog / android app (at http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/02/17/android-activites-and-tasks-series-an-introduction-to-androids-ui-component-model/).

Comment: Just started reading those blog posts; they're a very good, clear explanation of what's going on with Intent flags and Activities. Far better than the manual!