# Android - What Intent does home button issue?

Tags: android

I would like to know exactly what operation a devices home button performs?  ie what intent, intent category and action is issued when you click on home button? that takes on back to the blank home screen.   I would like to know what is involved in implementing this operation to occur when clicking on my own custom button.  Thanks  (PS I know it is not standard, but neither is my device).

Answer (score 14):

If you want to show the home screen, you can do it by:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Update: check this sample app: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html

Comment: What effect will this have on the application that issues it?   It will go to background?

Comment: Yes. It does not close the app, it only brings the home screen to the foreground.

Comment: Is that the same effect however of clicking the home button?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, yes. Bear in mind that any app can capture the keydown event and do whatever the app wants with it before the event gets passed (or not) to the framework (services.jar, if I remember correctly)

Comment: @Aleadam "It does not close the app" there's no such thing like "close the app" in Android.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intent in xml, in case you are looking for it:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved)

Also you should be able to see what happens after you click Home button from adb using logcat debug options like;

adb logcat *:W

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to the code：

```
Button btnHome;
btnHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Home);
btnHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // sendKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME);
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(Home);
    }
});

class myRunnable implements Runnable {

    public myRunnable(int key) {
        this.keycode = key;
    }

    int keycode;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sendKey(keycode);
    }

    public void sendKey(int keyCode) {
        System.out.println("Judy--------------------->sendkey " + keyCode);
        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        long n = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            KeyEvent down = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                    keyCode, 0);
            KeyEvent up = new KeyEvent(now, now, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,keyCode, 0);
            IWindowManager wm = IWindowManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager
                    .getService("window"));
            wm.injectKeyEvent(down, false);
            wm.injectKeyEvent(up, false);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse me what is `myHandler` ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D myHandler is a Handler.

Comment: really ? can you please explain your code ? there is no definition of myHandler in your code - please edit your answer explaining how it answers the question and let me know