# Resume Mobage Login Screen in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, game-development, social-gaming

I am using Mobage Gaming API. And I want to resume to my Mobage Login screen.

I am using following code:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (Mobage.isInitialized()) {
            Mobage.getInstance().onResume();
            Log.d("MobageResume", "MobageResume onResume()");

        }
    }
```

`Mobage.getInstance().onResume();` method is fired but nothing happens in the device. It is not display Mobage Login screen again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved now. It is due to AndroidManifest.xml in activity Android: launchMode=SingleTask. By removing this the Mobage Login screen is properly displayed.
For detail Please see following link:
[Android: launchMode=SingleTask problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017505/android-launchmode-singletask-problem)