# How start another package ontop of the stack?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, launching-application, launchmode

I have to app stacks like this:

A->B-C->D

X->Y

In Y I want to use getLaunchIntentForPackage("package") to get to D, however I get to
A. What launch mode should I use etc? I would like to use singleTask for ABCD if possible.
Also when in D and I press home and launch via the Icon for A again then depending on launch mode I don't get to D (that I would like), but to A. DCB are cleared.

I tried a lot of things but I just don't understand how it works. I don't seem to get a consequent behaviour.

Comment: I wrote an answer to my problem (using other links). See:

[Android: bug in launchMode=“singleTask”? -> activity stack not preserved][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved/26359365#26359365

Comment: I wrote an answer to my problem here:

**[Android: bug in launchMode=“singleTask”? -> activity stack not preserved][1]**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved/26359365#26359365

Answer (score 1):

- `getLaunchIntentForPackage` just gives you the Main activity of package. In your first app i am guessing it is `A`. So if you try starting it from 2nd app (`X`->`Y`), it will start `A` and not `D` which is a different activity. So you are not getting to `D`.
- When you press home and click launch icon for first app, if there is already a task for it, it is brought foreground. [Looks like `A`, the app's main activity (`A`) gets invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131632/launch-existing-singletask-activity-from-launcher-icon) - not the stack top activity `D`. And [B->C-D get cleared because you may be using `singleTask` launch mode for Activity `A`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268646/android-question-about-singletask-mode), which tries to take you back to activity in existing task.

So [what you observe is expected. The launch modes are defined per activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html), not per app/package level.

- So to get from `Y` to `D`, you need to start activity `D` using intent flag set to [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK), this will ensure you get to the existing `D`, that is already on top in your first task (A->B->C->D)
- To do the same from home screen (launcher icon) you [may need to try below options for `SingleTask` mode](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/mvkWWuZ50zc/ZWxfI57vG0cJ), since you want to preserve the existing stack (A->B->C-D) , and simply want get to `D`; Quoting from the link:

  ```
  "+ For launchMode=singleTask if there is an intent_filter in the
  manifest the task stack is always cleared after returning to Home and
  re-launching (returns to main activity instead of last activity).

  + For launchMode=standard re-launch from Home instead returns to last
  activity in task (as expected).

  + If there is no intent_filter listed then even with
  launchMode=singleTask re-launch from Home returns to the last activity
  in the task"
  ```

  - So, set your main activity launch mode to standard, it will let you preserve the stack as-is (2nd +point above). You can still start this in `singleTask` mode using intent-flags (eg: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)) from your other app. Intent flags [override manifest launch modes, see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes)

Comment: I don't understand why singleTask would clear my stack? But more importantly: how can I restart another package (a stack with activities) from my other package (app) without clearing the stack?

Comment: But I have to have an IntentFilter in singleTask otherwise it won't show up on Launcher -no?

Comment: @JohnyTex change your main activity launch mode to standard, it will let you preserve the stack as-is (2nd `+`point above). You can still restart another package in `singleTask` mode using intent-flags (eg: [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)) from your other app. Intent flags [override manifest launch modes, see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html#TaskLaunchModes).

Comment: But I dont want to start a new task, I want to call back my singleTask stack(!)

Comment: @JohnyTex it [wont start new task, just brings foreground existing task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) (with D at the top).

Comment: Thx, I will try it and if it works I owe you one, and then we can mark your comments as accepted answer.

Comment: No it doesn't help. My singleTask app stack is cleared when pressing home and relaunching using GetLaunchIntentForPackage using FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK!

Comment: Declare it standard task, call D activity with that flag.

Comment: No it doesn't work because then it launches the standard activity on top of the old stack. I just want to bring it back as it was. I want it to be singleTask, but it doesn't work!

Comment: In your question u had 1st app abcd alredy active. If you had A as standard, then getting to d using that flag will work. Re-read my update to answer and last few comments

Comment: OK so I how can I get launch intent for activity D using only package name?

Comment: Doesnt matter as long as you had A as standard. Getting to D with that flag will just bring forward existing stack/task. You need to call D directly, cant use getp... Function as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: OK thx! But what is the difference between launching from icon and getlaunchintentforpackage? How can I simulate launching from icon?

Comment: You can directly call activity.. Look up explicit intent.sorry i am on a phone

Comment: No worries. Answer if you like and have time! The problem I have is that I only have package name to work with...

Comment: Both usually end up referring to main activity A... We need to call D directly

Comment: But when people write launchers -how do they get from packages on disk to D?

Comment: If I use getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName) with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED), then it works with SingleTop (and probably standard), but not SingleTask. It seems singleTask always resets when pressing home, which makes me wonder whats the practical difference to singleInstance.

Comment: @JohnyTex SingleInstance keeps the task exclusive for that activity, no other activity allowed. So it ends up being just that one activity per task.