# Launch activity from service and stop previous activities after pressing Home Button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

One of my Activities is launched from Service with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
When I press back button and start this `Activity` it opens and when I press Back Button I see the regular Android home.
But if I press Home Button and then start my `Activity` from `Service` and press Back I see the previous Activity from my App.
But I'd like to see the regular Android home.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html. check this might help.

Comment: @Raghunandan But I don't like to disable Home Button. I just want to set right flags. But don't know how. I tried different and all is without any result...

Comment: check the activity back stack and see how it works. when you press back button your current activity is popped from back stack and destroyed. the previous activity in the backstack takes focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeeded to do it with the help of:

1. launchMode: singleInstance, as @gunar said
2. FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
3. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
4. [taskAffinity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759556/flag-activity-exclude-from-recents-excludes-whole-application-not-only-the-acti)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to have a single instance of that `Activity`. The way I see it you have 2 options:

1. If you don't care about how many activities you have on stack, or how they are organized, you can set the [`launchMode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) to `singleInstance` in your application manifest.
2. `singleInstance` is not recommended for most apps (The link I have provided you doesn't detail too much why, but that is a different story). Or if you have multiple activities, then having an activity with this launch mode may not be appropriate. You need to handle the case when you have your activity on stack or you don't have it. From service you can send an [ordered broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendOrderedBroadcast%28android.content.Intent,%20java.lang.String%29) that your activity can process and abort if it's on stack (in your activity #onCreate() and #onDestroy() you will register, resp un-register that receiver. Remember to register with a high ordinal). More on ordered broadcast receivers [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ro/2011/01/processing-ordered-broadcasts.html). So if the activity is on the stack, you will receive that intent and drop the broadcast. If the activity is not on the stack then another broadcast receiver **with a lower priority** will receive that intent - in this case, your service. So, again: onCreate and onDestroy - register resp. unregister the broadcast receiver. In its `onReceive()` method you will handle what you're doing now - open the Activity with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! The first method helps me to stay at Home Screen. But when I select my App from the tray - it starts that activity. I tried to set Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY but got an unexpected behaviour.
Your second method will help to avoid such behaviour, won't it?

Comment: What unexpected behavior? I would always follow the 2-nd approach.

Comment: In tray I have a black image and when I press on it, activity opens.

Comment: By "tray" are you reffering to "recent apps" or do you have some kind of notification in the status bar?