# What Are the Differences Between FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am in the process of (finally) writing the chapter on tasks for my book, and I am encountering a few lingering puzzles.

Things that serve as home screen launchers seem to use the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` when they launch the requested launcher activity:

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
i.setComponent(name);

startActivity(i);
```

[The documentation for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED) has:

> If set, and this activity is either being started in a new task or bringing to the top an existing task, then it will be launched as the front door of the task. This will result in the application of any affinities needed to have that task in the proper state (either moving activities to or from it), or simply resetting that task to its initial state if needed.

That's not especially clear.

In particular, it would seem that the same effects would be seen using a combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. Quoting the docs for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent...
>
> The currently running instance of [the desired activity] will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().

The `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` documentation makes sense, at least to me.

So, what does `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` do that is different than the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`?

---

Bonus points if you can explain what [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) does that is different from either of the other two options described above.

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), this flag will cause any existing task that would be associated with the activity to be cleared before the activity is started. That is, the activity becomes the new root of an otherwise empty task, and any old activities are finished. This can only be used in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

One obvious difference between this and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` | `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` is that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` needs `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. But, other than that, it would seem like the net effects are the same, and also match `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`.

Comment: I remember that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` do something specific when used with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET`, but apparently this flag is now deprecated and its documentation has disappeared ([old doc can be found here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.0FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)). It now says to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` but I'm not sure that it does the exact same thing.  This is a bit confusing...

Comment: @Dalmas that's just a renaming.  If you look at the code, NEW_DOCUMENT is set to be equal to CLEAR_WHEN_RESET.  They are the same thing.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had a look at the source code for the `ActivityManager`. The flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` does indeed do some magic that `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` does not do: It triggers **task reparenting**.

Here's an (albeit lame) example:

In App A we have the root Activity `RootA` and we have another Activity `ReparentableA`:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".RootA">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ReparentableA"
            android:allowTaskReparenting="true"/>
</application>
```

App A has the package name "com.app.a" so the default `taskAffinity` of its components is "com.app.a".

In App B we have the root Activity `RootB`:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="RootB">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

App B has the package name "com.app.b" so the default `taskAffinity` of its components is "com.app.b".

Now we launch App B from the HOME screen. This starts a new task and creates a new instance of Activity `RootB` as the root Activity in that task. Activity `RootB` now launches Activity `ReparentableA` in the standard way, without any special flags. An instance of `ReparentableA` is created and put on top of `RootB` in the current task.

Press HOME.

Now we launch App A from the HOME screen. This starts a new task and creates a new instance of Activity `RootA` as the root Activity in that task. NOTE: When Android launches a "launcher" Intent, it automatically sets the flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`. Because of this, launching `RootA` now triggers task reparenting. Android looks to see if there are any activities in any other tasks that have an affinity for this new task (and are reparentable). It finds `ReparentableA` (which has the same task affinity as `RootA`) in the App B task and moves it to the new App A task. When launching App A we do not see `RootA`, we actually see `ReparentableA`, as it is moved to the top of the new task.

If we return to App B, we can see that `ReparentableA` is gone from the task stack and that task now consists of only one Activity: `RootB`.

---

Notes about using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`

The important thing to remember about using these flags to "reset a task" is that **it only works if there is already an instance of the target Activity at the root of the task**. If your root Activity ever finishes, you cannot clear your task by starting the root Activity with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`. Android will just create a new instance of the target (root) Activity and put it **on top of the existing activities in the task**, which is probably not at all what you want.

---

Difference between `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`:

As noted above, using `CLEAR_TOP | SINGLE_TOP` only works if there is already an instance of the target Activity in the task. `CLEAR_TASK`, however, removes all activities from the task, regardless of whether or not there was an instance of the target Activity in the task. Also, using `CLEAR_TASK` ensures that the target Activity becomes the root Activity of the task, without you needing to know what Activity was the root Activity before you cleared the task.

---

Difference between `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED`:

As indicated above, using `CLEAR_TASK` will **always** remove all activities from the task and launch a new instance of the target activity. In contrast, `RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` will only reset the task in certain situations (the "IF_NEEDED" part). The task is only "reset" if Android is either:

- Creating a new task (in which case the "reset" functionality involves the task reparenting explained above), or
- If Android is bringing a background task to the foreground (in which case the task is only cleared of any activities that were launched with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` and any activities that are on top of those activities). NOTE: The root Activity is never cleared in this case.

---

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** When you are testing, please note that there is a difference in the way Android behaves when launching apps from the HOME screen (or from the list of available applications) and when selecting tasks from the recent task list.

In the first case (launching an app by selecting it from the list of available applications or from a shortcut on the HOME screen), a launcher `Intent` with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` is created. This is used regardless of whether or not the app is already running. The `Intent` is launched and then the `ActivityManager` figures out what to do.

In the second case (selecting a task from the list of recent tasks), if the task still exists, it is just brought the front. The task "reset" is NOT performed if the task is just brought to the front using the recent task list. It isn't obvious to me how this is managed and I've not had a chance to look through the source code to figure out why that is.

---

I hope this answers your questions. Looking forward to your feedback and test results.

Comment: Many thanks! I'll run some tests related to this on the weekend.

Comment: First round of tests done, using [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Tasks/TaskCanary). I can reproduce your `CLEAR_TOP|SINGLE_TOP` and `NEW_TASK|CLEAR_TASK` results with two notes. First, `startActivity()` with `CLEAR_TOP|SINGLE_TOP`, to start the current top activity has zero effect -- it doesn't even start a second copy, which fits the `CLEAR_TOP` docs.

Comment: Second, `startActivity()` with `NEW_TASK|CLEAR_TASK` works as expected, so long as the activities are from your app. If the activity you are starting is from another app, even one with no task affinity, it seems to start a task-less activity. In my sample app, click "Other Activity" from the overflow of the launcher activity, then click the "Settings Activity, CLEAR_TASK|SINGLE_TASK" button. The date settings screen appears. Press HOME. Then go into the recent-tasks list and go back to TaskCanary, and you are taken to the activity with the buttons. There is no task for the Settings app. Weird.

Comment: Regarding youjr first note, you can use `CLEAR_TOP` when launching any activity in the task, and it will clear the stack back to that Activity (with the note that `SINGLE_TOP` or `launchMode="singleTop"` will have an effect on whether or not it reinstantiates or reuses the existing instance of the Activity). It doesn't need to be the root Activity. My comments about `CLEAR_TOP` were only in reference to using it to "clear a task" (as per your question). Regarding your second note, that does sound weird. I'll have to look at this later.

Comment: Final round of tests done. Your `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` explanation is spot on. https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Tasks/ReparentDemo demonstrates it, with the `app/` module being your A and the `aux/` module being your B. I'll be pointing back here and giving you full credit for the analysis for these parts of my tasks chapter. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I might be mistaken here, but in my understanding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` does analyze **all** tasks and makes sure that only one task with launcher activity is running.

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` will inspect current task only, so you might end up with 2 launcher instances running at the same time (if the first one was created as a separate task).

Comment: That makes sense. I'll need to run some experiments. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how you could have more than 1 task with the launcher activity running, unless you use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` which should really only be used if you are coding a HOME screen replacement and then only if you offer a way to distinguish between multiple tasks running the same root Activity.

Answer (score 0):

1) FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED

If some task is pending,than it will destroy that process and will start the activity that you requested

2) FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

If any previous intent of this activity is running,than this method will deliver the running instance of the activity,close all other activities and will start activity with previous instance.

3) FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

If recently this activity has been launched,and instance is saved,than it will not launch this activity.

Comment: This is merely parroting documentation, much of which is already quoted in the question.

Comment: I'm changing(improving and explaining),Wait for few till i finish explaining

Comment: I am skeptical that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` terminates any processes, but I will test that as part of my work on these answers this coming weekend. Thanks!

Comment: What, exactly, is a "pending task"?

Comment: I can confirm that `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` does not appear to terminate a process.