# Android : Pending Intent Not Firing if the application is not in foreground

Tags: android

I am trying to open an activity when user clicks on `Notification`. I had issued following `Intent` as pending `Intent`

```
Intent caseIntent = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);
caseIntent.putExtra("priority", priority);
caseIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, caseIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

But when I click on the notification, if the app is not in forground the active which I have specified is not opening at all.
Is something wrong with this `Intent`?

Comment: Start by switching from `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to `0`. If nothing else, use *one* of those flags, not both, but in this case you should need neither of them. Beyond that, the combination of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is odd. There are probably [better combinations to use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29376250/115145).

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare . It helped a lot Thanks