# PendingIntent not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to start service using `PendingIntent`. `Notification` shows but on click of it `onStartCommand` of service not working.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(EasyTouchService.this,"my_channel_id_01");

Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(EasyTouchService.ACTION_SETTINGS);
settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent settingsPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(EasyTouchService.this, 1, settingsIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //also tried o and some others

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.eight_ball_img);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
mBuilder.setContentText("Open Settings");
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Stop Service", stopPendingIntent);
mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_rotate, "Show/Hide", hidePendingIntent);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(settingsPendingIntent);

mNotification = mBuilder.build();

// setUpAsForeground(message);
mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

//updateNotification("Hide Pattern");
mNotification.tickerText = getString(R.string.app_name);
int NOTIFICATION_ID = 121125;
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Adding `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` is useless in an `Intent` to start a `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

set Flag as:

```
settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your intent Flag to **FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP**, like this:

```
settingsIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

For further reference/explanation see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321261/what-are-the-differences-between-flag-activity-reset-task-if-needed-and-flag-act) post

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, myService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to start a `Service` using an implicit `Intent`. This doesn't work. You should see a message in your logcat that it is insecure to start a `Service` using an implicit `Intent`.

Try using an explicit `Intent` to start your `Service`. An explicit `Intent` specified exactly which component (class) will be launched. Something like this:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(EasyTouchService.ACTION_SETTINGS);
settingsIntent.setClass(EasyTouchService.this, EasyTouchService.class);
```