# Behaviour of app launch with the mainActivity launchMode set to `singleTask`

Tags: android, android-intent

The launcher activity of my app is defined with this intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

I specified the `launchMode` for this activity as `singleTask`.

According to the second answer of this question - [Android default launchMode of LAUNCHER activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636026/android-default-launchmode-of-launcher-activity) it shouldn't make any difference. But in my case every time I minimise the app and then relaunch it using the app icon the `LauncherActivity` is being brought to the forefront with intent flags - `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT`. This is causing the `LauncherActivity` to start on top of the existing task.

While for `standard` and `singleTop` launch modes there is no problem. The `LaunchActivity` is not being instantiated again.

Is this an anomaly or am I somewhere wrong in my understanding?

Comment: This article explains its pretty well, https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Comment: @niranjankurambhatti I went through the article earlier. I was asking about the effect that `singleTask` launch mode has in the context of the main launcher activity. I couldn't find anything specific to that in the article

Comment: what behaviour do you want? generally, we do not give any launch mode to the starting activity.

Comment: Ya that’s what I am doing now. Just that I can’t understand the behaviour of app for singleTask launchMode in main launcher activity