# android does not return to the latest activity when using singleTask mode

Tags: android

My main activity is set to use the `singleTask` model, and activity2 will be started through main activity, if I press the `Home` button at the `activity`, and then enter my application again I will go in to the main activity rather than the latest activity `activity2`.

And I  have googled ,and found a same problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved/3002890#comment29217180_3002890) and it have got a solution.

However when I use google map, I found that it does not use any solution mentioned in the post.

The `MapActivity` of Google Map is `singleTask` with a `MAIN` intent-filter.

But if you see [this](http://imgbin.org/images/15515.gif), you will find that use will get back to the latest activity.

What solution may google map use?

Comment: Nothing happen when I click back button(But the `up` icon will be invisible), still at the `mainActivity`, and I will exit if I click back again.

Comment: When you press home button and again launch app you enter `MainActivity`. Now if you press back button what happens.

Comment: check this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html might help

Comment: @Raghunandan: http://imgbin.org/images/15518.gif This is my app workflow.

Comment: override the activity life cycle methods and log some info there for each of the activities. Check the log. your activities are destroyed and so it launches MainActivity

Comment: Destroyed? Why, does return HOME will cause the app to be destroyed? If so , any idea to avoid it? BTW, from the post I mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved/3002890#comment29217180_3002890, it seems that this is caused by the `singleTask` .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40234/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-hguser)

Comment: use singleTop instead of singletask an try

Comment: OK, I will have a try.