# Using singleTask in launchMode

Tags: android, android-activity, launchmode

I added singleTask attribute to MainActivity(A) to avoid loading the activity multiple times. After the other activity(B) is on MainActivity(A->B), if I go back to home screen by pressing home button and re-launch the application, there is no B (A->B->HOME->A)

There IS an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417468/android-bug-in-launchmode-singletask-activity-stack-not-preserved), saying to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP every time calling A Activity.

BUT, I have a Intent data scheme in Manifest file, and the application should be launched by the scheme.

Please, help me...

Comment: if you want to resume your app..then why you use flags which will clear the activity stack..

Comment: How you resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like Android is launching your `MainActivity`(A) again after you return to the HOME screen. This shouldn't happen, but is a long-standing nasty Android bug. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283079/re-launch-of-activity-on-home-button-but-only-the-first-time/16447508#16447508) for more information.